# Firebase hosting deploy error "HTTP Error: 404, Not Found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I don't know if this is related to the recent bump of firebase-tools to 6.0 or not. But I'm unable to deploy my files to a hosting project.

The output after I type firebase deploy:

```
=== Deploying to 'legofun-8f22d'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[legofun-8f22d]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[legofun-8f22d]: found 42 files in /_site
(node:10178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
    at new FirebaseError (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/error.js:9:18)
    at Object.reject (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/utils.js:67:31)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/hosting/prepare.js:48:26
    at arrayEach (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:516:11)
    at Function.forEach (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9344:14)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/hosting/prepare.js:29:7)
    at _chain (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:22:40)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:63:16
    at 
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
(node:10178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10178) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
⠏  hosting: adding files to version [0/42] (0%)(node:10178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
    at new FirebaseError (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/error.js:9:18)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:38:12)
    at Request._callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:37:35)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request. (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage. (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
(node:10178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)

Error: HTTP Error: 404, Not Found
```

Comment: try updating your firebase-tools ? :S

Comment: I did already, just in case :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Ever since I ran `firebase target:apply hosting`. Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Bn5ja0j

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem

In my case I fixed it by adding on the firebase.json a dot before /dist on public tag `"public": "./dist/my-app-name",`

Example of my json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./dist/my-app-name",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: for those on multiple site using firebase target:apply hosting

do not forget to add, `"target": "targe-name",`

Answer (score 5):

Was facing the same issue, my problem was that I had deleted the project in the console but the source-code was still referencing it hence error 404 - resource not found.

My solution was to:

- delete **.firebaserc** file (contains your project alias) located in the root of the project
- run `firebase init` and link to your project
- run `firebase deploy` again

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error while trying to follow the [Starting with React Most Wanted codelab step "Prepare Firebase Databases"](https://start-with-rmw.web.app/#4)

> Error: HTTP Error: 404, Project 'react-most-wanted-ef689' does not exist.

Where `'react-most-wanted-ef689'` would contain the name of any project.

It seems that I didn't set up Firestore properly.  Missing step:

Activate Firestore for the project and specify the Resource Location Id by following [Get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

I don't think it was in the codelab, so maybe this is something new since the codelab was written.

Comment: Thanks! I've used firebase extensively for a while and this tripped me up when I was quickly making a staging environment/project... I forgot you have to manually create the firestore on the web ui...

Answer (score 4):

make sure you choose a default storage location for your firebase project, then deploy again.

here's how:

in firebase project > project overview > gear icon > project settings > Default GCP resource location

You can simply go to firebase console > storage > enable firebase storage.

And It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to your firebase console
- Go to setting->General and there you will see **Default GCP resource location**
- Set GCP location to nam5 (us-central)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

I a similar issue and had to run the following to make it work

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

See [Get started: write and deploy your first functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the public directory reference. 
Deploy. It will give error.
Changed it back to original. 
Serve then check. 
Deploy.

Comment: I got the error when i changed the name, but after fixing the directory it did not work. I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom of "Firebase Console > Hosting Page" click on "Add another site" and create them with the same name you used for target.

Answer (score 0):

The Only Problem to solve the problem was that the internet connection was not stable.As soon the internet connection was connected correctly so this is how I solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Default GCP Resource Location in your Project Settings.

This fixed it for me.